# How to Query DATE To TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I  want to query `DATE` Value `YYYY/MM/DD` to `TextBox`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdate" 
             runat="server" 
             BorderColor="Black" 
             TextMode="DateTime" 
             Width="180px">
</asp:TextBox>
```

That's the code is my `TextBox`

```
dtadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr, con);
dtadapter.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{  
    DateTime Gogogo = (DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["Start_Deprec"];
    txtdate.Text = Gogogo.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I don't remember asp textbox got this mode DateTime. Anyway you can just Gogogo.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try;

```
txtdate.Text = Gogogo.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

You can further read more about [`DateTime.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this One:

```
using System.Globalization;//namespace    

DateTime From = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "yyyy/MM/dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Read more about : [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method